# VPN without Static IP address

Tags: vpn, remote-access, remote-desktop, openvpn

I have some servers in my workplace and they are accessible via Intranet, I want to allow people from external network to access the gateway and all resources in that gateway.

Is there any way to do that without any special hardwares???

I tried installing **Hamachi LogMEin** ( Gateway Network ) but, it is taking too much time to connect using RDP.

I tried **Insta Safe**, they are charging bit high!

Comment: Are you wanting to connect VIA RDP or for them to connect to the gateway? i.e. `TeamViewer / SimpleHelp` would be able to help with a remote connection (RDP) but that wouldnt create a virtual `VPN`

Comment: No not like RDP , i want to access all resources in the network , ESX Server , vCenters etc even the gateway also

Comment: And have you tried `OpenVPN`?

Comment: OpenVPN requires static IP rit ?

Comment: Even if it does (I am not 100% sure), why not then just use a free dyndns address (which masks your IP address)?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming. I'm not sure what site would be more appropriate, perhaps Superuser or I note there is http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ whcih sounds like it coudl be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not programming related, I thought I would provide you with a solution which should help resolve your issue using OpenVPN and a Dynamic IP address.

Please follow this [URL](http://forums.untangle.com/openvpn/16283-site-site-vpn-over-dynamic-ip-addresses.html)

Snippet:

[image]

As Chris mentioned, should you need further assistance, please try an alternative website, perhaps the suggested [networkengineering](http://www.networkengineering.stackexchange.com)  would suffice.